# I have trouble with some pointers, access location failed at the end of debugging

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl

```
// header.h
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Biblioteca
{        
public:
    Biblioteca();
    void closeFile();
    bool chose();
    ofstream Intrare;
    ofstream Memorare;        
};

class Publicatii:public virtual Biblioteca
{        
public:
    string retTitlu();
    string retEditura();
    string retAutor();
    int retAn();
    int retTiraj();
    int retNumar();
    int retFrecventa_de_aparitii();

protected:
    string Titlu, Editura, Autor;
    int An, Tiraj, Numar, Frecventa_de_aparitii;

};

class Carti: public Publicatii , public virtual Biblioteca
{
public:
    void readBook();
    Carti();
    void insertMyBook();
    void writeBookFile();

    void inTitlu(Carti& a);
    void inEditura(Carti& a);
    void inAutor(Carti& a);
    void inTiraj(Carti& a);
    void inAn(Carti& a);

protected:
    list<Carti*>books;
    list<Carti*>::iterator i;
};

class Reviste: public Publicatii , public virtual Biblioteca
{
public:
    void readMagazine();
    Reviste();
    void insertMyMagazine();
    void writeMagazineFile();

protected:
    list<Reviste*> magazine;
    list<Reviste*>::iterator j;
};
```

The other cpp file of the header

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"biblioteca.h"
#include <list>
#include<fstream>
//-----Biblioteca------

Biblioteca::Biblioteca()
{
    Memorare.open("in.txt");
}
void Biblioteca::closeFile()
{
    Memorare.close();
}
bool Biblioteca::chose()
{
    int k;
    cout << "Ce doriti sa introduceti?" << endl << endl;
    cout << "1--Carte" << endl;
    cout << "2--Biblioteca" << endl;
    cin >> k;
    switch (k)
    {
        case 1:
            return true;
            break;
        case 2:
            return false;
            break;
    }
}
//-------Publicatii------

string Publicatii::retTitlu()
{
    return Titlu;
}
string Publicatii::retEditura()
{
    return Editura;
}
string Publicatii::retAutor()
{
    return Autor;
}
int Publicatii::retAn()
{
    return An;
}
int Publicatii::retTiraj()
{
    return Tiraj;
}
int Publicatii::retNumar()
{
    return Numar;
}
int Publicatii::retFrecventa_de_aparitii()
{
    return Frecventa_de_aparitii;
}

//---------Carti---------
void Carti::inTitlu(Carti& a)
{
    Titlu = a.retTitlu();
}

void Carti::inEditura(Carti& a)
{
    Editura = a.retEditura();
}
void Carti::inAutor(Carti& a)
{
    Autor = a.retAutor();
}
void Carti::inTiraj(Carti& a)
{
    Tiraj = a.retTiraj();
}
void Carti::inAn(Carti& a)
{
    An = a.retAn();
}

void Carti::readBook()
{
    cout << "\nO noua carte" << endl<<endl;
    cout << "\nTitlu= ";
    cin >> Titlu;
    cout << "\nEditura= ";
    cin >> Editura;
    cout << "\nAn= ";
    cin >> An;
    cout << "\nTiraj= ";
    cin >> Tiraj;
    cout << "\nAutor= ";
    cin >> Autor;
}

Carti::Carti()
{
    books.resize(1);//one book
}

void Carti::insertMyBook()
{
    Carti carti;
    for (i = books.begin(); i != books.end(); i++)
    {
        carti.readBook();
        (*i)->inTitlu(carti);
        (*i)->inEditura(carti);
        (*i)->inAn(carti);
        (*i)->inTiraj(carti);
        (*i)->inAutor(carti);
        //books.insert(i, *i);
    }
}

void Carti::writeBookFile()
{
    Memorare << "---Carti---" << endl;
    for (i = books.begin(); i != books.end(); i++)
        Memorare << *i << " ";

}

//-------Reviste--------
void Reviste::readMagazine()
{
    cout << "\nO noua revista" << endl<< endl;
    cout << "\nTitlu= ";
    cin >> Titlu;
    cout << "\nEditura= ";
    cin >> Editura;
    cout << "\nAn= ";
    cin >> An;
    cout << "\nTiraj= ";
    cin >> Tiraj;
    cout << "\nNumar= ";
    cin >> Numar;
    cout << "\nFrecventa de aparitie= ";
    cin >> Frecventa_de_aparitii;
}

Reviste::Reviste()
{
    magazine.resize(1);//one magazine
}

void Reviste::insertMyMagazine()
{
    Reviste reviste;
    for (j = magazine.begin(); j != magazine.end(); j++)
    {
        reviste.readMagazine();
        //some conde
        magazine.insert(j, *j);
    }
}

void Reviste::writeMagazineFile()
{
    Memorare << "---Reviste---" << endl;
    for (j = magazine.begin(); j != magazine.end(); j++)
        cout << *j << " ";
}
```

Sorry for the code thone here, I'm new to Stackoverflow and I'm in a hurry, that's why I don't write "beautiful code". My problem is, when I want to just insert elements in my list

```
void Carti::insertMyBook()
{
    Carti carti;
    for (i = books.begin(); i != books.end(); i++)
    {
        carti.readBook();
        (*i)->inTitlu(carti);
        (*i)->inEditura(carti);
        (*i)->inAn(carti);
        (*i)->inTiraj(carti);
        (*i)->inAutor(carti);
        books.insert(i, *i);
    }
}
```

it's working like a clockwork and after I compile I type some information from my keyboard and at the end I get a big error like "Acces Violation Reading 00000001C"
Why? I tried other metods like allocating dynamic memory with the new operator, I tried a lot of things but in the end I have like this error or type "example" doesn't match with "example".
Sorry for my bad English spelling, but in this program I just wanted to make a program that reads magazines and boooks and stored to a library named "biblioteca", and "carte" means books and " Reviste" means magazine... and I want it to be memorized in a list because I need to insert elements or delete what ever book or magazine I choose...and all the information I want to be saved in a file for instance "out.txt" or "in.txt"

Comment: I can't really work out what's going on as your code is quite messy. However, access violation usually indicates you're dereferencing an invalid pointer / iterator. Also, why isn't `i` declared within the for loop?

Comment: The code you're asking about looks like it's replacing every book in the library with the one you just read. You might want to look over your logic a bit. And writing less code before you start testing it makes bugfinding much easier. BTW, you should avoid storing pointers in your lists unless your teacher explicitly requires it.

Comment: i thought you need the itterator to go along with the list, you can increment a simple variable like "i" to wrok out with the list like a vector container?

Comment: Anytime you have an access violation of the form "...reading/writing 0x000000NN" it nearly always means you're trying to dereference NULL pointer, almost always to a structure or class object, and the member being dereferenced-to is at the aforementioned offset. In your case that offset is `1C`, or 28 bytes in to *something* (by the looks of it, a `Carti`. Since nowhere in your code do you seem to actually *allocate* memory for the the ill-advised pointers in your list, that would explain quite a lot.

Comment: And what you suggest to do in this case?How to do it? "if (*i!=Null) do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash is because the iterator is `NULL` at line `(*i)->inTitlu(carti);`.

The issue is in method:

```
Carti::Carti()
{
    books.resize(1);//one book
}
```

and books are:

```
list<Carti*>books;
```

What you are trying to is to resize the list of Carti's to 1 but as you have a *list of pointers to Carti objects* rather than *Carti objects*, resizing operation will not create a Carti object by calling it's constructor but a pointer.

Apart from that you have major issues with your design and coding, a Carti object storing a list of other pointers-to-Carti objects definitely is not a good idea. You may consider creating another 'holding' class to store a list of Carti's you have created.

Comment: Thanks Koray for your answer ! Thanks a lot !